# why is my try and except not working correctly? python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't know why my try and except isn't working properly.  I want it to continue anytime the user inputs either the string "y" or "n", but if the user doesn't input any of those then print the error.

output:

```
userInput = input("Are both players ready to start? (y/n): ")
k (userInput)
Here we go!
```

---

expected output:

```
userInput = input("Are both players ready to start? (y/n): ")
k (userInput)
Wrong Input, Try Again
```

---

```
try:
  if userInput == "y":
    print("Here we go! ")
    print()
  elif userInput == "n":
    print("Too bad we're starting anyways")
except:
  print("Wrong Input Try Again)
```

Comment: There is no exception to be thrown if the user adds no input, just neither of your conditions are True. Then there's no outer loop to make it ask again.

Comment: There's a missing string quote, it should read `print("Wrong Input Try Again")`.That's probably not your answer though

Comment: just use if, elif, else (don't use try, except).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the try block, you are not raising an error so there is nothing to catch. Adding a raise should do the trick.

```
userInput = input("Are both players ready to start? (y/n): ")
try:
  if userInput == "y":
    print("Here we go! ")
    print()
  elif userInput == "n":
    print("Too bad we're starting anyways")
  else:
    raise ValueError("What's up with that?")
except:
  print("Wrong Input Try Again")
```

As suggested by @ctrl-alt-delor you can also skip the `try/except` block and only use an `if/else` block. This snippet should do the same:

```
  if userInput == "y":
    print("Here we go! ")
    print()
  elif userInput == "n":
    print("Too bad we're starting anyways")
  else:
    print("Wrong Input Try Again")
```

Comment: it gave me the error: raw_input is not defined.  I think it's because this is python 3.7

Comment: Ok nevermind that part, I just realized I'm on python 2.7. I will edit my answer

Comment: raw_input of python 2, is now input in python 3

Comment: While your code will work. Why throw and catch an exception, when you can just deal with the input error in the else?

Comment: so it'll say "Wrong Input Try again" but it will still continue my code

Comment: Maybe he wants to handle input interruptions? @ctrl-alt-delor I'm not sure.

Comment: @ChamongLo `if/elif/else` will do the same!

Comment: ok so i have written the game of war card game, and i ask the user if they are ready to start, but if they input something other than the strings y and n, I want it to say "Wrong input try again", until they  put in the write input

Comment: Maybe, so will this code handle input interruptions?

Comment: error and exceptions

Comment: I add the suggestion from @ctrl-alt-delor in the answer, maybe you can try if that works? It will make your code easier to read in my opinion

Comment: okay it think i found my problem.  I had a function after my statements and was continuing because the input was after them.  Will i need a while loop to keep asking until the question is answered properly?

Answer (score 2):

There is no error raised in your code, so `except` is never called. If you want to raise your own exception, use the `raise` keyword. Details here : https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#raising-exceptions